# locally measurable functions

Tags: integration, measure-theory, measurable-functions, outer-measure

In the books of Boubarki on integration, the autors define $L^\infty$ spaces with the help of *locally* negligible subsets. In the books of Fremlin (and other classical books), the author does not seem use *locally* negligible subsets. What is the link between these two approaches  (probably in the non-$\sigma$ finite case)?